# Powershell -include $variable trouble

Tags: arrays, powershell, get-childitem

Why doesn't $arraychoices work in this gci?.. But if I hard code the file type extension in it does?

Doesn't work

```
$filetypes = @()
$filetypes += '*.pdf'
$filetypes += '*.txt'
$ftc = $filetypes
$arraychoices = "('$($ftc -join "','")')"

$fr = Get-ChildItem C:\backuptest **-include $arraychoices** -Recurse 
$files = $fr.fullname
$files
```

Harcode Works?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\backuptest **-include ('*.pdf','*.txt')** -Recurse
```

What am I missing?  Im my above example.  Im using check boxes for file type extensions, so the hard code method isn't an option.

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: There's a difference between the string `'a,b'`, and an array of strings `'a','b'`. Skip the `$ftc`/`$arraychoices` step completely: `Get-ChildItem -Include $filetypes`

Comment: O wow. How did I miss that.  Works great.  Thanks for your time Mathias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$filetypes` is *already an array of strings* - pass it directly to the `-Include` parameter:

```
$filetypes = @()
$filetypes += '*.pdf'
$filetypes += '*.txt'

Get-ChildItem -Include $filetypes ...
```